# runtime error: could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-4.0

When I hold my mouse over <%@ Page I get this error 
and it seems like it tries to load a file/assembly that is no longer valid. How could I fix this?

Comment: Restart Visual Studio :)

Comment: Do you have (or have you had) any plugins installed?

Comment: If all else fails, try to find out what DLL it can't find using ProcMon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a binding error, try running Fusion